# Refresh a page after entering it?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, bbpress

I'm using WordPress with the plugin bbPress.

So far, so good.

The only thing I'm stuck at, is the fact that for certains functions to appear (like Approve Reply, Close Topic etc.) I need to refresh the page, otherwise the buttons won't appear.

How can I implement a sort of a function in order to refresh the current page just after I clicked on it?
So that basically when I enter this page, it gets automatically refreshed (and so the buttons will appear).

Thank you!

Comment: Javascript `location.reload();` will do

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. It's very unusual to force a refresh on a page upon loading it. Why exactly don't your buttons show up on load?

Answer (score 0):

You can use header function this way:
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);